# Express.js application bug: category name is taken for post id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I have *Posts* that are grouped into *Categories*, each in its own collection.

I filter posts by category: all posts in the *Sport* category are displayed at `http://localhost:3000/sport`, all posts in the *Travel* category are displayed at `http://localhost:3000/travel`.

For this purpose I introduced the route `router.get('/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory);`:

```
const express = require('express');
const postsController = require('../../controllers/front-end/posts');

// Express router
const router = express.Router();

// Get Posts
router.get('/', postsController.getPosts);

// Get Posts by Category
router.get('/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);

module.exports = router;
```

Categories do get filtered by category, but router.get('/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory); and `router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);` are conflicting in such a way that *single posts are no longer displayed*.

That is because posts IDs are taken for category routes.

In the controller I have the 2 methods `getPostsByCategory` and `getSinglePost`:

```
exports.getPostsByCategory = async (req, res, next) => {

    function titleize(slug) {
        var words = slug.split("-");
        return words.map(function(word) {
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }).join(' ');
    }

    const postCategory = new RegExp(titleize(req.params.catname),"ig");

    const singleCategory = await Category.findOne({cat_name:postCategory})

    const posts = await Post.find({ category : singleCategory }, (err, posts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('default/index', {
                moment: moment,
                layout: 'default/layout',
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                page_heading: 'XPress News',
                page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                posts: posts.reverse(),
            });
        }
    }).populate('category');
};

exports.getSinglePost = (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            } else {
                res.render('default/singlepost', {
                    layout: 'default/layout',
                    website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                    post: post
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In the view for (all) the posts I have:

```
<p class="post-meta">Posted in <a href="/<%= post.category.cat_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); %>"><%= post.category.cat_name %></a>, on <%= moment(post.created_at).format( 'MMM-DD-YYYY') %></p>
```

I would like to fix this issue in a manner that keeps the pattern `http://localhost:3000/category-name` for the URLs that display posts in categories.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is important to you to keep the pattern `http://localhost:3000/:param` both for single post and post by Category, you can use only one route method handling both requests

```
// This will handle Get requests both for Posts by Category and single Post
router.get('/:param', (req, res, next) => {
    // If :param is Mongo ObjectId call the getSinglePost method.
    if (req.params.param.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        postsController.getSinglePost(req, res, next);
    } 
    else {
        postsController.getPostsByCategory(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

I just added a middleware, which check the request parameter. If it's type of ObjectId, you call getSinglePost method, otherwise call getPostsByCategory method.

The only you have to do is to replace `req.params.catname` and `req.params.id` with `req.params.param` inside both methods of your `postsController` file.
You can also remove the match check in the getSinglePost method, since it is implemented in the route file.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to do this "compromise": categories at `router.get('/category/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory)`; all posts at `router.get('/', postsController.getPosts); `and single post at `router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost)`?

Comment: You are correct, but my intention is to use the post's slug in it's url, instead of the pos's id. Hence, the comment above.

Comment: If you want to use as parameter a slug name, instead of Id, then you should find another way to determine which method to call. But i see that inside your method you check for an ObjectId, if you pass a slug name as parameter, it will fail

Comment: I will change *all* that in the *future*. Meanwhile, I tried with `<a href="/category/<%= post.category.cat_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); %>"><%= post.category.cat_name %></a>` in the **Posts** view and `router.get('/category/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory)` in the routes file and the problem is my assets do not load at `http://localhost:3000/category/category-name`. :(

Comment: is page rendered?

Comment: Yes, but the CSS and JS file are not found for some reason. Anyway, this is another issue. Thanks for the answer, it makes a lot of sense and it opened my mind. :)

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213277/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-dimitris-tseggenes).

Answer (score 2):

Well these both are actually the same route:

```
// Get Posts by Category
router.get('/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);
```

I would suggest to create different routes for example:

```
// Get Posts by Category
router.get('/category/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/post/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);
```

Comment: That is the obvious (and easy) solution. I want to keep the pattern `http://localhost:3000/category-name` for the URLs, for SEO purposes.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you would need 1 controller instead of 2 `getPostsByCategory` and `getSinglePost`. There you would need to check if your param is a post ID or category name. Therefore you also dont need 2 routes if i understad you right

Comment: The methods `getPostsByCategory` and `getSinglePost` are both in the same controller. Are you suggesting there should be one method instead of these two?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir yea. my idea was to put both in 1 method. and in that method you check if its a category name or id

Comment: @RazvanZamfir i know. thats why i suggest to split it up with 2 routes. one thing you can do is to create a method called for example `checkParam()` there you check if its id or category name. then you return your methods `getPostsByCategory` or `getSinglePost`